# OneSignal duplicate push notifications

Tags: java, android, firebase, onesignal

So, I've created an app from a template, and that works fine. I had to edit a lot, but made it work very well. Anyways, the template has an admin panel for texts to be inserted into the app, and a push notification system using OneSignal/Firebase, but I never used it because I never managed to send images with it (which you can see in the upper part of my screenshot). It's like it sends the image, but it doesn't display it. Fast forward, I'm trying to send notifications directly via OneSignal dashboard, and it sends them just fine. But it also sends that in-template notification, which you can see in the upper part of the screen. I know it's from the app, because it's using my push notification icon, and the OneSignal one is using the bell icon. So, How to disable those integrated notifications?

[image]

Comment: Have you find the solution for this yet?